# How to handle Heap Size while Calling API?

Tags: apex, rest-api, api

I am trying to get data from API using Apex like following:-

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://MyEndpint');
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
// If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
    Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
}
else{
    System.debug('Error*****');
}
```

Problem is data returned from API endpoint is more than `12MB` which is exceeding heap size than available and data will grow in future

one option is if API provider can provide pagination option to API and I can retrieve data in chunks but if that option is not available what is the alternative.

Can anyone please advise how we can handle such situation ?

Comment: Yes being able to get the data a piece at a time is the simplest. Or implement outside Salesforce e.g. write your own intermediary service that your Apex calls and that does the HTTP request and write back into Salesforce. In a world where laptops have 16G of memory, the 6M/12M heap limit (x1000 smaller) is pretty ridiculous and ought to grow to reflect the normal payload sizes of today, not those of 10 or more years ago.

Comment: Thank you @KeithC , do you have any reference which I can check to develop external service on another platform and consume in Apex, to be honest I am not much familiar with other platforms . If you could provide me or have any reference handy with you, I will try to follow the steps accordingly. Will be good learning ,Thanks Again.

Comment: If you know one of the stacks that Heroku supports - see https://www.heroku.com/ - use that. But if not, then it's a lot of work to learn how to do this and too much for an answer here. You might be able to find a middleware product that can do this (e.g. Mulesoft) but the cost side could be a problem.

Comment: Got it , Thanks for your help @KeithC